# Ime action not being updated on TextField switch inside Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, ime, android-compose-textfield

I have multiple `TextFields` and with the ime action `Next` the user can jump until the last one which has the ime action `Done`. What I have noticed is that, even the cursor is inside the last `TextField`,  the ime action is not being updated. It still says `Next` and stays like this until I type something into the TextField (the action behind the button is correct, even when I click on the "Next" the "Done" action of the last TextField is being executed). In order to reproduce this issue it is enough to have two TextFields and by tapping inside them the ime action should be updated, but it is not, it always stays at the value from the `TextField` from which the keyboard initially popped up)

```
    TextField(
        value = text1.value,
        onValueChange = {
            text1.value = it
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onNext = {
                Log.d("Screen", "NEXT")
            }
        )
    )
    TextField(
        value = text2.value,
        onValueChange = {
            text2.value = it
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = {
                Log.d("Screen", "DONE")
            }
        )
    )
```

Did someone notice this issue too or has a solution to it? Also tried wrapping the `KeyboardOptions` inside a mutableState and update its value depending on the currently focused item (to force a recomposition) but it did not help.

Comment: I have tested this code in emulator and my device it's working when I tap on second ```TextField``` it show me done icon.

Comment: That is true, inside my simulator it also works. Also with my Samsung S7 (Android 8) it works. But with my Samsung A71 (Android 13) it does not work :(

Comment: I'm using android 13 samsung galaxy note 10 lite

Comment: I have tested the code with an inclusion of a `FocusManager` and `SoftwareKeyboardController` on my Galaxy A52 (API 33), and it seems that the the IME action button of the Samsung Keyboard is stuck and won't change until the button receives some sort of interaction. [Here is a gif demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bU7.gif).

Comment: Yes that is the behavior that I have on my A71. It seems that it is device dependent but definitely looks like a bug